# Unable to display app full screen on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-fullscreen

I create an image in my activity and then I display it. But the image is not full screen as there is a white border around it ! The screen is supposed to display the image and flash at the same time. Here is my Java code:

```
public class DisplayData extends Activity {

    float minBright = 0;
    int patch = 25;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


       this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);// no need to write another    

        //time//
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        ViewFlipper imageFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById( R.id.image_flipper );

        //I removed the irrelevant part of the code
      ImageView image = new ImageView ( getApplicationContext() );

        image.setImageBitmap(GridBitmap);

        imageFlipper.addView( image );

        imageFlipper.setFlipInterval( 2000 ); 
        imageFlipper.startFlipping();

        Thread thread = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {

                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(bl1);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
                                    layout.screenBrightness = maxBright;

                                    getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(wh1);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
                                    layout.screenBrightness = minBright;

                                    getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        };

        thread.start();

    }
```

}

Here is the XML file (This is only one activity, the application contains another one ):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/image_flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the padding from your layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/image_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```